# habilitar un input con un checkbox, js php y mysqli

Tags: php, javascript, html5, base-de-datos

estoy buscando hacer crear una calculadora de calorias, con valores traidos de la base de datos. para ello quisiera que los datos de kcla se habilidata cuando hago click en el chekbox, pero no se mucho sobre js. espero puedan ayudarme. Gracias

````
   <?php
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla"; 
       $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); //consulta
       desconectar($conexion);
       if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0 ){ ?>
           <form action="mostrar.php" method="post">
           <table id="myTable">
                   <tr class="header">
                       <th style="width:5% ;"></th>
                       <th style="width:25 %;">nombre</th>
                       <th style="width:20%;">kcal (100g/ml)</th>
                       <th style="width:20 %;">Grupo</th>
                       <th style="width:15 %;">Cantidad</th>
                       <th style="width:12% ;">kcal totales</th>                  
                   </tr>           
               <?php while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){ 
                   ?>
                       <tr>
                       <th><input type="checkbox" onChange="comprobar(this);" name="<?php echo $fila['nombre'];?>" id="<?php $fila['nombre'];?>"></th> //cheackbox usar para desabilitar input de calorias
                       <td><label for="<?php $fila['nombre'];?> "> <?php echo $fila['nombre'];?> </label></td> 
                       <td>  <input type="text" style="display:none" disabled value="<?php echo $fila['kcal'];?>" name=" <?php echo 'kcl_'.$fila['nombre'];?>_"> </td> //cambiar con js de desabled a realonly
                       <td><label for="<?php $fila['grupo'];?> "> <?php echo $fila['grupo'];?> </label></td>
                       <td> <input type="text" name="" id=""></td>
                       <td> <input type="text" name="<?php echo 'kcl_'.$fila['nombre'];?>" id=""></td>
                       </tr>
                       <?php }?>
           </table>
           <input type="submit" value="enviar">
           </form>
           <?php }?>
    ```
````

la idea de la función es que habilitara la propiedad solo lectura en el input de kcal de la columna correspondiente

```
   <script>
   function comprobar(obj){
     if (obj.checked){
       document.getElementById('seccion').disabled = false;
     } else{
           
     document.getElementById('seccion').disabled = true;
     }     
   }
   <script>
```

Comment: Hola, puedes decirnos lo que intentastes? Para ello te recomiendo leer [.disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled) y [onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Comment: Hola amigo, estás utilizando jQuery? O simple javascript? Si estás trabajando con jQuery te recomiendo leer [Cómo deshabilitar o habilitar un elemento de un formulario con jQuery (en inglés)](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-disable-enable-a-form-element/)

Comment: Gracias por responder, solo estaba usando js, todavia estoy aprendiendo a usarlo y lo que intentaba hacer es que solo el elemento de Kcla de la misma fila que yo seleccione en el checkbox cambie de disabled a realonly

Answer (score 0):

usando el id, logre conseguir lo que queria, dejo codigo con la soluccion que llegue.

```
$conexion = conectar();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tabla";
    $resultado = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
    desconectar($conexion);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($resultado) > 0 ){
        ?>
        <article id="tabla_busq">
        <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">
        <form action="mostrar2.php" method="post">
        <table id="myTable">
                <tr class="header">
                    <th style="width:5% ;"></th>
                    <th style="width:35 %;">nombre</th>
                    <th style="width:10%;">kcal (100g/ml)</th>
                    <th style="width:20 %;">Grupo</th>
                    <th style="width:10 %;">Cantidad</th>                  
                </tr>           
            <?php while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)){
                ?>
                  <tr>
                    <th><input type="checkbox" onChange="comprobar(this);" name="<?php echo $fila['nombre'];?>" id="<?php echo $fila['id'];?>"></th>
                    <td><label for="<?php $fila['nombre'];?> "> <?php echo $fila['nombre'];?> </label></td>
                    <td> <input type="text" class="tama1" disabled realonly value="<?php echo $fila['kcal'];?>" name=" <?php echo 'kcl_'.$fila['nombre'];?>_" id="name<?php echo $fila['id'];?>"> </td>
                    <td><label for="<?php $fila['grupo'];?> "> <?php echo $fila['grupo'];?> </label></td>
                    <td> <input type="number" class="tama2 Can_kcl" name="<?php echo 'cant_'.$fila['nombre'];?>" style="display:none" id="sel<?php echo $fila['id'];?>"></td>
                  </tr>
                  <?php }?>
        </table>
        <input type="submit" value="enviar">
        </form>
        </article>
```

y este es el codigo js

```
   function comprobar(obj){
      var kcal = document.getElementById("name" + obj.id);
      var cant =  document.getElementById("sel" + obj.id);
      if (obj.checked){
        kcal.disabled = false;
        cant.style.display = "";
        cant.required = true;
      } else{
    cant.style.display = "none";
    cant.required = false;
    kcal.readonly = true;
    kcal.disabled = true;
  }
```